# How do I have to configure pacemaker for OpenShift Origin V3

Tags: centos7, openshift-origin, pacemaker

I want to fake an enterprise environment with OpenShift Origin V3 to test some stuff.
I'm going to try the advanced installation with multiple masters, etcds and multiple nodes.
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html

I already did the quick installation once (running OpenShift in a container) and I did the advanced installation a few times (one host which contains a master + a node, and some nodes).

First of all, I'm installing the whole environment on AWS EC2 instances with CentOS7 as OS. I have 2 masters (master1.example.com and master2.example.com) and 3 nodes (node1.example.com, node2.example.com, ...)
I want to seperate my masters and nodes. So containers and images will only be on the nodes. (So no host which contains a master and a node).

My masters needs to be HA. So they will use a virtual IP and pacemaker. But how do I have to configure this? There are some tutorials to use pacemaker with apache. But there is nothing that describes the configuration of pacemaker and vip for using it in OpenShif.

Answer (score 0):

great news, I had to deal with pacemaker as well but now Pacemaker is not the native HA method for Openshift anymore(from v3.1). So we can get rid of the tedious pcs configuration and fencing tunning.

Now ansible installation playbook's take care of multiple masters installation, with what they called Openshift HA native method. No additional setup is required for a standard configuration.

Openshift HA method takes advantage of etcd to select the active leader every 30s(by default)

There is a method to migrate from Pacemaker to native HA
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/upgrading/pacemaker_to_native_ha.html#install-config-upgrading-pacemaker-to-native-ha